# Linux-Create AP that gets internet from client

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, hostapd

I'd like to create access point that will take the internet from one of its clients. In other words, is there a way to create a bridge with a client?

I know how to create AP and bridge it with ethernet but I do not know how to do above.

Let's imagine the following scenario:
There is a phone with internet access(PH1). There is also another phone with no internet access(PH2). There is also a PC with no internet access. On this PC there is a WLAN AP set up. How to configure that AP in order to get internet from PH1 and share it to PH2 and other devices?

Speed performance does not matter at that point.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser...Try to be more specific. Have you a laptop, a desktop, how many network interfaces in the client etc etc... Remember that you may [edit] your post to add such information.

Answer (score 0):

An access point is *already* a bridge; the AP will always relay data between all its clients unless deliberately told not to. So as long as you don't accidentally enable "client isolation", it should just work by default.

(Bridging just connects things, it doesn't specifically define where the device "gets the internet from".)

However, you'll usually have poor performance, since Wi-Fi is half-duplex – the AP can't send and receive at the same time (even between different clients).

Answer (score 0):

Beware that for security reasons, 802.11 APs are not allowed to accept packets from MAC addresses that have not authenticated and associated to the AP. That rule affects your client that is providing a path to the Internet.

If that client is a router (or NAT gateway), then your plan should work, because routers put their own source MAC address on packets they forward. But if you were planning on having that client be a *simple bridge* between wireless and wired Ethernet, then it won't work, because bridges don't change the source MAC address of packets they forward. So the AP will see those packets as coming from MAC addresses that have not authenticated or associated to the AP, and it will reject those packets. If you want to have a device *bridge* packets into your AP, you need the device to either do proxy authentication/association on behalf of all MAC addresses it sees, or you need to set up the AP and client as WDS nodes (some devices support acting as a WDS node at the same time as being an AP or client).